# Open in browser crash

Tags: bug, android-app

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: vivo
- Device Model: vivo 1609

  - OS Version: 6.0 (1503158401)

When I clicked "open in browser" option in More Options, the app crashed.